# Is it sufficient to control for two variables, or would I need three dummies? (R)

Tags: r, variables, statistics

I am computing the potential increase in the probability of attending college based on whether or not individuals go through a "college training program". Some are drawn to the training program through competitive exams and some are drawn randomly. However, among those drawn randomly, females and non-white people are favored according to this table:

```
               Female   Male

White           10.3%   5.3%
Non-White       15.1%   10.4%
```

In my model, I am using lottery as an instrument and want to control for gender and race in order to get the true effect of the training. However, I do not know if it is enough to control for my two binary variables "white" and "female", or if I would get a more precise result if I create new dummies "white_female", "non-white_female" and "non_white_male". The results are quite similar...

Output table, the two to the right are the ones mentioned:

[image]

Thank you for your answer! :-)

```
mods[['IV Lottery contr2']] <- estimatr::iv_robust(college ~ training + white_female + non_white_female + non_white_male | lottery + white_female + non_white_female + non_white_male, data = training_center)
summary(mods[['IV Lottery contr2']])
```